# FreeRDP issues with full-screen and multiple monitors

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

We have two computers running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Both computers have two 1680x1050 monitors attached.

When I run FreeRDP on one computer with the `/f /multimon` command, the remote session runs in fullscreen mode across both monitors, and the remote session treats them as two separate displays.

However, when I run the exact same command on the other computer, the remote session opens on screen 2 and running in a single, large window (3360x1050).

Can anyone help me identify the cause of this?
Could it be an issue with the graphics cards?

The full command I run from the terminal is `xfreerdp /f /multimon /u:username /v:(server address)`

**Edit:** I am using version 1.2.1-dev of FreeRDP

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  We're very sorry, but problems in development versions of software applications should be reported [on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that the developers are aware of the problem and can *actually fix them!*.  Here at the Ask Ubuntu Q&A we're not (all) developers with access to (all) the source code repositories... :-(